# PHP Display option depending on value

Tags: php

I am editing a part of a script that displays gender of a person but trying to add additional options.

The form that saves the information saves it as a value.

In my lang file this is what i have got related to the part i am trying to change :

```
$LNG['powner'] = 'Pet Owner';
$LNG['dog'] = 'Dog';
$LNG['cat'] = 'Cat';
$LNG['rabbit'] = 'rabbit';
```

The part of the code im trying to display is

```
    ((!empty($profile['gender'])) ? '<div class="sidebar-list">'.$LNG['ttl_gender'].':
<strong>'.(($profile['gender'] == 1) ? $LNG['powner'] :($profile['gender'] == 2) ?
 $LNG['cat'] : ($profile['gender'] == 3) ? $LNG['rabbit'] : $LNG['rabbit']).'</strong>
</div>' : '').'
```

But it will only display cat or rabbit ...

I am thinking that the code is set to be one or the other because this works :

```
    ((!empty($profile['gender'])) ? '<div class="sidebar-list">'.$LNG['ttl_gender'].'
: <strong>'.(($profile['gender'] == 1) ? $LNG['dog'] : $LNG['cat']).'</strong></div>' 
: '').
```

after the code if follows

```
'.((!empty($profile['website'])) ? '<div class="sidebar-list">'
.$LNG['profile_website'].': <strong><a href="'.$profile['website'].
'" target="_blank" rel="nofllow">'.$LNG['profile_view_site'].'</a>
</strong></div>' : '').'
```

Comment: code in a single line is not very readable and wont encourage people to help you.

Comment: sorry ill sort that now

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be re-written to say:

```
if(!empty($profile['gender']) {
    echo '<div class="sidebar-list">'.$LNG['ttl_gender'];
} else {
    echo "<strong>";
    if($profile['gender'] == 1) {
        echo $LNG['powner'];
    } else {
         if($profile['gender'] == 2) {
             echo $LNG['cat'];
         }
         else {
              if($profile['gender'] == 3){
                 echo $LNG['rabbit'];
              } else {
                  echo $LNG['rabbit'];
              }
         }
    }
}
```

As you see the code using shorthand If/Else statements is confusing to read, and can lead to mistakes. Re-write your functionality in more readable way, and you will prevent errors, and confusion with regards to what the actual conditions should be.

I'm assuming that the problem you're having is that the users you're testing this on are either gender 2 or 3, and never 1.

Comment: yes that's correct its always 2or 3 :) i tried replacing your code with the current code and i cant get it error free i get a syntax error. as there is more code above and below it.

Comment: the code before ends with .' and the next bit of code after starts with '. if thats any help

Comment: more like the same code same as before i have updated my question